# How do you do a simple counter in Javascript functional programming?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, counter

I am redoing my coding to better fit functional programming and I can not find a good solution to a simple counter without mutation.

```
const countRows = (element) => (obj) => {
var count = 0;
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key,value]) => {
    if (value.nodeName == element) {
      count = count + 1;
    };
  });
  return count;
};
```

I have been trying to figure it out using a helper function and recursion but nothing seems to be working out unless I use some type of mutation. I feel like this is something that should be super simple but I just cant wrap my head around how this is suppose to work. At least I have contained the mutation to within the function and not a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
Object.keys(obj).filter(key=>obj[key].nodeName == element).length
```

Comment: That was a quick answer and it worked perfectly. Let me ask you this, are there counters in functional programming or do you just have to think of a different way to solve the problem like you just did?

Comment: Super. We need to think of one if we have some certain conditions, because we are not counting all elements or looking up the same structure. The filter, reduce, forEach, and map methods provide different ways of simplify that.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution will make an array of the macthes for the sole purpose to count the elements. You can easily make a counting version of filter where the extra allocations doesn't happen:

```js
function countIf (coll, predicate, context) {
  return coll.reduce((matches, value) => predicate.call(context, value) ? matches + 1 : matches, 0);
}
```

It is compatible with the underscore line of higher order functions AND 
it even works with Backbone collections. Here is hwo I would have implemented `countRows`:

```js
const countRows = (element) => (obj) => 
  countIf(
    Object.keys(obj), 
    value => obj[value].nodeName == element);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have been trying to figure it out using a helper function and **recursion**

I would like to give you a **recursive solution**, even if [@Orbis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8023022/orabis) has already given you a very good solution.

## Steps

- check if object has entries

  - object has entries, check if object value is equal provided x

    - remove first object entry and increment the counter
    - else remove only the first object entry
- else return the counter which is by default `0`

## Code

#### "Longer" Version

```js
const isEqualObjectValue = ([key, value], x) =>
  value === x

const countRows = (objectEntries, x, counter = 0) => {
  if (objectEntries.length > 0) {
    if(isEqualObjectValue(objectEntries[0], x)) {
      return countRows(objectEntries.slice(1), x, counter + 1)
    } else {
      return countRows(objectEntries.slice(1), x, counter)
    }
  } else {
    return counter
  }
}

const test = {
  a: ':o',
  b: 'x',
  c: ':o',
  d: ':o',
  e: 'x'
}

console.log('how many \':o\' can you find:', countRows(Object.entries(test), ':o'))
```

#### "Shorter" Version

```js
const isEqualObjectValue = ([key, value], x) =>
  value === x

const countRows = (objectEntries, x, counter = 0) =>
  objectEntries.length > 0
    ? isEqualObjectValue(objectEntries[0], x)
      ? countRows(objectEntries.slice(1), x, counter + 1)
      : countRows(objectEntries.slice(1), x, counter)
    : counter

const test = {
  a: ':o',
  b: 'x',
  c: ':o',
  d: ':o',
  e: 'x'
}

console.log('how many \':o\' can you find:', countRows(Object.entries(test), ':o'))
```